# How to make this function easier to test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have the function which builds and return Slack message with `text` and `attachments`. How can I refactor this function to make it easier to test? Should I split it into multiple functions?

```
def build_list_message(team_id, user_id, msg_state=None, chl_state=None):
    if not msg_state:
        msg_state = {}

    if not chl_state:
        chl_state = {}

    resource_type = msg_state.get('resource_type', 'all')
    availability = msg_state.get('resource_availability', 'all')

    pages = Page.objects.none()
    async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.none()

    if resource_type in ['web_pages', 'all']:
        pages = Page.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if resource_type in ['async_tasks', 'all']:
        async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if availability == 'available':
        pages = pages.filter(available=True)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=True)

    elif availability == 'unavailable':
        pages = pages.filter(available=False)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=False)

    channel_id = chl_state.get('channel_id')
    if channel_id:
        pages = pages.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)

    user = SlackUser.retrieve(team_id, user_id)

    attachments = [
        _build_filters(resource_type, availability),
        *[_build_page_item(p, user) for p in pages],
        *[_build_async_task_item(at, user) for at in async_tasks]
    ]

    return {
        'text': "Here's the list of all monitoring resources",
        'attachments': attachments
    }
```

Here is private functions:

```
def _build_filters(resource_type, availability):
    resource_types = [
        {"text": "All types", "value": "all"},
        {"text": ":link: Webpages", "value": "web_pages"}
    ]

    availability_choices = [
        {"text": "Available / Unavailable", "value": "all"},
        {"text": ":white_circle: Available", "value": "available"},
        {"text": ":red_circle: Unavaliable", "value": "unavailable"}
    ]

    selected_resource_types = list(filter(
        lambda t: t['value'] == resource_type, resource_types))

    selected_availability_choices = list(filter(
        lambda a: a['value'] == availability, availability_choices))

    return {
        "fallback": "Resource filters",
        "color": "#d2dde1",
        "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
        "callback_id": "resource_filters",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "resource_type",
                "text": "Type",
                "type": "select",
                "options": resource_types,
                "selected_options": selected_resource_types
            },
            {
                "name": "resource_availability",
                "text": "Available",
                "type": "select",
                "options": availability_choices,
                "selected_options": selected_availability_choices
            }
        ]
    }


def _build_page_item(page, user):
    return {
        "fallback": "Page",
        "color": page.status_color,
        "mrkdwn_in": ["fields"],
        "callback_id": 'page_change',
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": page.title,
                "value": f"_Page_ ({page.status})"
            },
            {
                "title": "URL",
                "value": page.url
            }
        ],
        "footer": _build_resource_footer(page),
        "actions": _build_resource_item_actions(page, user)
    }


def _build_async_task_item(async_task, user):
    return {
        "fallback": "Async task",
        "color": async_task.status_color,
        "mrkdwn_in": ["fields"],
        "callback_id": 'async_task_change',
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": async_task.title,
                "value": f"_Async task_ ({async_task.status})"
            },
            {
                "title": "URL",
                "value": async_task.url
            }
        ],
        "footer": _build_resource_footer(async_task),
        "actions": _build_resource_item_actions(async_task, user)
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If it works, you're good.

Comment: I want to be sure that it works if I'll change something later

Comment: @offeltoffel https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/

Comment: @offeltoffel, sorry but saying why would you want to test things is a bit absurd.. why test anything?? errmm to make sure it works !! and continues to work even after refactoring.. in a professional working environment unit testing is standard practive and very good to learn as standard practce if you don't already. +1 roganjosh

Comment: Well, yes, I see it now. I use different practices for my work, but I'm not an IT professional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost certainly split this into multiple functions. You'll have fewer test cases that are simpler.

Let's take a look at how to do that. Because you're looking to add more tests, I'll stick to safe refactoring that you can do in an IDE like PyCharm.

NOTE: I'm doing this refactoring in the SO answer editor, so it's untested. There may be typos or missing parameters.

The first thing that jumps out at me is you have several assignments to `pages` and `async_tasks`

```
def build_list_message(team_id, user_id, msg_state=None, chl_state=None):
    ...

    pages = Page.objects.none()
    async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.none()

    if resource_type in ['web_pages', 'all']:
        pages = Page.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if resource_type in ['async_tasks', 'all']:
        async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if availability == 'available':
        pages = pages.filter(available=True)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=True)

    elif availability == 'unavailable':
        pages = pages.filter(available=False)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=False)

    channel_id = chl_state.get('channel_id')
    if channel_id:
        pages = pages.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)

    ...
```

These seem to be cohesive values based on the code, so I'm going to extract a single function that chooses them.

```
def page_and_async_task(resource_type, availability, team_id, chl_state):
    pages = Page.objects.none()
    async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.none()

    if resource_type in ['web_pages', 'all']:
        pages = Page.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if resource_type in ['async_tasks', 'all']:
        async_tasks = AsyncTask.objects.filter(
            user__team__team_id=team_id).order_by('title')

    if availability == 'available':
        pages = pages.filter(available=True)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=True)

    elif availability == 'unavailable':
        pages = pages.filter(available=False)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(available=False)

    channel_id = chl_state.get('channel_id')
    if channel_id:
        pages = pages.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)
        async_tasks = async_tasks.filter(alert_channel=channel_id)

    return pages, async_tasks

def build_list_message(team_id, user_id, msg_state=None, chl_state=None):
    if not msg_state:
        msg_state = {}

    if not chl_state:
        chl_state = {}

    resource_type = msg_state.get('resource_type', 'all')
    availability = msg_state.get('resource_availability', 'all')

    pages, async_tasks = page_and_async_task(resource_type, availability, team_id, chl_state)

    user = SlackUser.retrieve(team_id, user_id)

    attachments = [
        _build_filters(resource_type, availability),
        *[_build_page_item(p, user) for p in pages],
        *[_build_async_task_item(at, user) for at in async_tasks]
    ]

    return {
        'text': "Here's the list of all monitoring resources",
        'attachments': attachments
    }
```

So now you can write 6 tests for `page_and_async_task`, then mock that function when you test `build_list_message`. The mock function just needs to return valid pages and async_tasks.

Next, I'm going to consider the single responsibility principle. Your function is responsible for building a dict with the keys `text` and `attachments`. It can delegate to something else.

```
def build_list_message(team_id, user_id, msg_state=None, chl_state=None):
    if not msg_state:
        msg_state = {}

    if not chl_state:
        chl_state = {}

    resource_type = msg_state.get('resource_type', 'all')
    availability = msg_state.get('resource_availability', 'all')

    pages, async_tasks = page_and_async_task(resource_type, availability, chl_state)

    user = SlackUser.retrieve(team_id, user_id)

    attachments = make_attachments(resource_type, availability, pages, async_tasks, user)

    return {
        'text': "Here's the list of all monitoring resources",
        'attachments': attachments
    }

def make_attachments(resource_type, availability, pages, async_tasks, user):
    return [
        _build_filters(resource_type, availability),
        *[_build_page_item(p, user) for p in pages],
        *[_build_async_task_item(at, user) for at in async_tasks]
    ]
```

The entrypoint is still doing a little too much - it breaks up the inputs, calls SlackUser.retrieve, which presumably reaches out to the database, and builds a message.

```
def build_list_message(team_id, user_id, msg_state=None, chl_state=None):
    if not msg_state:
        msg_state = {}

    if not chl_state:
        chl_state = {}

    resource_type = msg_state.get('resource_type', 'all')
    availability = msg_state.get('resource_availability', 'all')
    user = SlackUser.retrieve(team_id, user_id)

    return _build_list_message(team_id, user_id, resource_type, availability, chl_state, user)


def _build_list_message(resource_type, availibility, chl_state, user):
    pages, async_tasks = page_and_async_task(resource_type, availability, chl_state)

    attachments = make_attachments(resource_type, availability, pages, async_tasks, user)

    return {
        'text': "Here's the list of all monitoring resources",
        'attachments': attachments
    }
```

Now you can test the top level function, mocking it's helpers. Then for each mock you made, you'll owe a test for the helper that shows it behaves the same as the mock, all the way down until the end. Then write a single test that runs the real thing and shows everything works together.

For steps after this, you may want to apply the strategy pattern to make injecting your helper functions simpler.